# Soap Api Integration in Android

Tags: android, api, soap, dolibarr

Is there anyone knows how to create third party user, Invoice, Order and user login in [Dolibarr](https://www.dolibarr.org) using SOAP api?

Answer (score -1):

Below xml format for getuser details from dolibarr

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.dolibarr.org/ns/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getUser soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <authentication xsi:type="ns:authentication">
            <!--You may enter the following 5 items in any order-->
            <dolibarrkey xsi:type="xsd:string">superuser api key</dolibarrkey>
            <sourceapplication xsi:type="xsd:string"></sourceapplication>
            <login xsi:type="xsd:string">your login id</login>
            <password xsi:type="xsd:string">your pasword</password>
            <entity xsi:type="xsd:string">your entity</entity>
         </authentication>
         <id xsi:type="xsd:string">user id's under your entity</id>
         <ref xsi:type="xsd:string"></ref>
         <ref_ext xsi:type="xsd:string"></ref_ext>
      </ns:getUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```